# Specifying and simplifying sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

I was doing the following question:

> Find a simpler way to specify the set $A=\big\{ X: X\in \Bbb N \cap \{-5,3,7,11\} \cup \{-5, -3, 13\} \big\}$

Am I right to suggest a simpler way of specifying the following sets is

$$A=\big\{X:X\in \Bbb N \cup \{-5,-3\} \big\} ~?$$

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but $\mathbb{N}\cap\{-5,3,7,11\}\cup\{-5,-3,13\}$ seems to be ambiguous. Are there no brackets left?

Comment: @julius Yes, sorry it should be {X:X N∩{-5,3,7,11}} U{-5,-3,13}

Comment: Julius is right, the intersection with $\mathbb N$ removes $-5$ from the first finite set but this element is added back, from the union with the second finite set. So you just take the union of the 2 finite sets, disregarding "$\mathbb N\cap$".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd start by noting that ${\bf N}\cap\{{-5,3,7,11\}}=\{{3,7,11\}}$.

Comment: And from there you would do {3,7,11}∪{-5,-3,13} = {3,7,11,-5,-3,13}
so the answer would be 
A={X:X∈N∩{3,7,11,-5,-3,13}} ?
Thanks.

Comment: It seems to me that the simplest specification for the set won't have $\bf N$ in it at all. I note that the question has been edited since I posted my answer, and I think the edit has changed the problem.

Comment: @Fatz: No, you would have $\{x:x\in\{-5,-3,7,11,13\}\}=\{-5,-3,7,11,13\}$